# The <a href> link not working on click

Tags: jquery, html, href

This my HTML code

```
<body>
    <div class=sidebar>       
                <ul class=nav>
                    <li class="home1"><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
                    <li class="bye"><a href="bye.php">BYE</a></li> 
                </ul>
     </div>

  <script>

var regex = /1$/
$("ul.nav li").on('click', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this), clickclass = $this.attr("clickclass");

    e.preventDefault();

    if(!regex.test(clickclass)){
        $this.removeClass(clickclass).addClass(clickclass + 1);
        $this.siblings('[class$="1"]').attr('class', function(idx, clickclass){
            return clickclass.substring(0, clickclass.length - 1)
        });
    }
});

</script>
```

When I click on the link "BYE" it doesn't load the bye.php page it stays on the default home.php... Please help

Comment: Firstly it's not working because you have `e.preventDefault()` in there. Secondly, you're returning from a `click` handler, which is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
e.preventDefault();
```

prevents all the eventhandlers from invoking, including the redirect.

You can add

```
window.location.replace($(this).attr("href"));
```

when your validation succeeds.

Comment: it still doesn't work when i remove the preventdefault line...when i add 'code'window.location.replace($(this).attr("href"));'code' below the closingbracket of if then it redirects to undefined page e.g /theme/undefined instead of theme/bye.php

Comment: @user1517784 - sorry, you're right. You are handling the `li` click event, not `a` nested in it, so use `window.location.replace($(this).find('a').attr("href"));`

Comment: did not working the moment i put the line in the class change stops applying

Answer (score 1):

remove

```
e.preventDefault();
```

it prevent the default event.I hope it will help